# How can I disable all sunday on datepicker?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, momentjs, vue-component, vuetify.js

I use vuetify datepicker and moment js

I want to disable sunday on datepicker

My code like this :

```
<v-date-picker
        v-model="date"
        :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
        class="mt-4"
        :min="currentDate"
        @update:picker-date="pickerUpdate($event)"
      ></v-date-picker>
```

My full code and codepen like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/qBBjaJr?editors=1010

How can I do it?

So I want to disable all Sundays in October, November and December

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious solution is to check the day of week before pushing the date to available dates:

```
if (moment(date).day() !== 0)
  availableDates.push(date)
```

https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/poowNjJ?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

I would just do simple check which day it is with either `dayjs` or `moment`

```
allowedDates(val) {
  return dayjs(val).day() !== 0;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue Datepicker have a build in filter to filter out or disable specific week day

0 bein Sunday
6 being Saturday

```js
  <template>
    <VueDatePicker v-model="date" :disabled-week-days="[6, 0]" />
  </template>
```